# Why is PHPMyAdmin throwing 403 error when pasting SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've never had this happen before, but when I try to copy/paste a SQL statement into my PHPMyAdmin window, it throws an error saying "Error in processing request.  Error code: 403.  Error text: error (rejected).  It seems that the connection to the server has been lost.  Please check your network connectivity and server status."

I can login and browse the tables, etc fine.  However, when I try to paste in a SQL statement to the SQL tab area, it throws this error.  Any ideas?  It also happens when I type in a SQL statement manually.  once it gets to a certain point, it throws the error.

Comment: This could mean anything first try another browser, then you can look into webdevelopertools and see if there is an error like soemthing wasn't loaded, a reboot is often a pronlemsover, when you didn't update anything or changed the php.ini file

Comment: @nbk Going to try the reboot tonight during off-peak hours to see if that fixes it.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying a few things first, I would check the level of permissions on your account. You could possibly have an account that is only granted read access and you are trying to run a query that reads then writes.

If you have the proper permissions I would try to run the SQL command from the command line. You can access the command line through the bin folder.

Let me know what happens, and I hope this helps!

Comment: It's only PHPMyAdmin.  When I run SQL directly it works fine.  It's a Windows/Apache install.  I'm going to try rebooting the server to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same problem with a very basic query:

> SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `created_at` > '2021-06-03 10:00:00' AND `price` > 40

and got the same error as the Author. When I removed second condition or just replaced second ">" with ">=" in WHERE statement the error has gone. So I have realized that this not a problem with query but with something on a different application level.

After small research I've found information that this is some kind of filtering on web aplication level like firewall preventing from SQL injection. This is why the same statement works from CLI but not from PMA. So it is all about server/firewall configuration and this problem is already known:

- https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq5-21
- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16778
- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16533

Hopefully this helps people who are looking for a solution to this problem (or at least a starting point).

By the way, this is my first post on SO, so hello to everyone!